# How to sum the maximum value of each column in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet of numbers. How do I take the maximum value from each column, and summarize them using only **one** formula? (No temp cells, no scripts.)

```
1  2  1
0  1  3
0  2  0
```

For the table above the result should be 6 (1+2+3, the maximum value of each column). But I'd like a solution that works for much larger tables, too.

As a more general question, I'd like to find out how I could fold 2D ranges into 1D arrays using an arbitrary operator (like `MAX` and `SUM` in this case).

Comment: Are you just looking for a basic answer, or an alternate approach? =SUM(MAX(A1:A3), MAX(B1:B3), MAX(C1:C3)) works for your query...

Comment: I'd like an ultimate approach for an arbitrary large table. Thanks! (I edited the question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your data in range A2:D, to get the maximum of every row (array output) try

```
=query(transpose(query(if(row(A2:D)>=transpose(row(A2:D)),transpose( A2:D)),"select max(Col1),max(Col2),max(Col3),max(Col4) ",0)),"Select Col2", 0)
```

If you need to process a lot of columns, this may be better

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( A2:D) , "Select "&"MAX(Col"&JOIN( ", MAX(Col",ROW(INDIRECT( "YY1:YY"&ROWS(A2:A)))&")"))), "Select Col2", 0))
```

To sum, just wrap SUM() around the above formulas.

Comment: Holy cow, man, it works. I don't understand half of it, but you gave me a very good pointer how to educate myself further. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

MAX by columns in `A1:C3`

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A1:C3},"Select "&"MAX(Col"&JOIN(", MAX(Col",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:C3))&")"),0),2)
```

MAX by rows in `A1:C3`

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:C3),"Select "&"MAX(Col"&JOIN(", MAX(Col",SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:C3))&")"),0),2))
```

Substitute MAX with MIN to get the minimums.